# Definition of a signature of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Why some authors consider  a signature of a billinear form of as a difference of the number of positive and negative eigenvalues of the matrix associated with the form. For example, the Minkowski space (+---) has the signature equal -2. Is it the only reason экономия бумаги?

Comment: Compared to what other definition?

Comment: They write it that way by convention, it doesn't make any difference to use one convention or another

Comment: ,,It doesn't make any difference to use one convention or another'' I do not agree at all. There are better and worse definition, meaningful and not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

,,It doesn't make any difference to use one convention or another'' I do not agree at all. There are better and worse definitions, meaningful and not meaningful. Linear algebra: congruent matrices: most students present the easiest algebraic definition, that there exist C such that C^T A C = B and have no idea what is the meaning of this relation. Solving problems on this relation without this knowledge is a bit ridiculous. A similar is with Lie algebras: the most common is to say that the sum [[x, y], z] over cyclic permutations is zero. But it is better to write it as ad [x, y] = [ad x, ad y]. This is what we have for Leibniz algebras.  More serious, there are some algebraic definition that have no sense in a more general situation. An example are contact structures in supergeometry.